Disable EF Core health check tracing
I'm adding a health check for my EF Core DbContext with the following code
builder.Services
       .AddHealthChecks()
       .AddDbContextCheck<MyDbContext>("MyDbContext");

This works nicely but generates a Span/Trace every 30 seconds or so in my Open Telemetry output. I'm using Aspire and configuring my otel output as follows
builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry()
        .WithMetrics((MeterProviderBuilder metrics) =>
        {
            metrics.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
                .AddRuntimeInstrumentation();
        })
        .WithTracing((TracerProviderBuilder tracing) =>
        {
            //Filter out health check requests from tracing, they fill the logs with noise
            tracing.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation((o) => o.Filter = (HttpContext context) => !context.Request.Path.Equals("/health"));
            tracing.AddHttpClientInstrumentation();
            tracing.AddSqlClientInstrumentation(options =>
            {
                options.SetDbStatementForText = true;
                options.EnableConnectionLevelAttributes = true;
                options.SetDbStatementForStoredProcedure = true;
                options.RecordException = true;
                //options.Filter = new Func<object, bool>((activity) =>
                //{
                //    SqlCommand cmd = activity as SqlCommand;
                //    //Exclude health check activities
                //    var b = !cmd.CommandText.Equals("SELECT 1");

                //    return b;
                //});
            });
        });

As you can see I've tried filtering out the "SELECT 1" health checks which gets call but doesn't appear to change the output. My aim is to disable all logs/spans/metrics related to health checks (ideally I'd like to log failures).
If versions make a difference I'm using .NET / Aspire 9.
